# Non exhaustive match (actually exhaustive)

Tags: rust

I am a Rust beginner and I like the idea of having a construct like match were the exhaustiveness of what I write is checked but I incur in problems with the compiler for doing very simple things which are actually correct, like the following.

How should I handle this situation? (Code explains itself in this case)

```
fn main() {
    let my_int = -29;
    match my_int {
        x if x < 10            => {println!("Foo")},
        x if x >= 10 && x < 20 => {println!("Bar")},
        x if x >= 20           => {println!("Baz")},
    }
}
```

The compiler says:

```
error[E0004]: non-exhaustive patterns: `_` not covered
 --> src/main.rs:3:11
  |
3 |     match my_int {
  |           ^^^^^^ pattern `_` not covered
  |
  = note: the matched value is of type `i32`
  = note: match arms with guards don't count towards exhaustivity
help: ensure that all possible cases are being handled by adding a match arm with a wildcard pattern or an explicit pattern as shown
  |
6 ~         x if x >= 20 => {println!("Baz")},
7 ~         _ => todo!(),
  |
```

Comment: For the purpose of the exhaustiveness check, the compiler considers `if` guards always as potentially non-matching. You can simply omit the guard from the last arm if it always matches.

Comment: Yes but it would make the code less readable, any way to get around this?

Comment: I don't think the code would be less readable by not providing redundant information, especially if you modify the second case to be `x if x < 20` I think that would make the cases clearer, as the previous case already provides the low bound for the accepted range.

Comment: You could add `_ => unreachable!()`, see https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.unreachable.html#examples

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is because the usage of the condition doesn't constrain the exhaustiveness of the types.  But you can write this:

```
fn main() {
    let my_int = -29;
    match my_int {
        ..=9    => {println!("Foo")},
        10..=19 => {println!("Bar")},
        20..    => {println!("Baz")},
    }
}
```

If you want to use `x`, you can do so like this:

```
fn main() {
    let my_int = -29;
    match my_int {
        x @ ..=9    => {println!("Foo: {x}")},
        x @ 10..=19 => {println!("Bar: {x}")},
        x @ 20..    => {println!("Baz: {x}")},
    }
}
```

Comment: error[E0658]: exclusive range pattern syntax is experimental. I am using rustc version 1.76.0 is that the latest patch?

Comment: This syntax works for me with rustc 1.76.0 (07dca489a 2024-02-04).  However, if I use `..` instead of `..=`, I get the same error you do, which is why I didn't use that syntax.

Comment: If the range limits were constants like ..=MY_CONST it works but what if the next match arm needed to be MY_CONST + 1, I tried using parenthesys but it doesn't parse it right. Have you tried?

Comment: @UmbertoFontanazza match arms work on patterns and constants, not arbitrary expressions. So `..=(MY_CONST + 1)` won't work. You could make another constant though.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `x` or `_` for the last entry. Alternatively, encode your ranges into an enum.

Rust does not (currently?) have range types or type refinements, so *as the compiler error tells you* the compiler is currently unable to compute match completeness based on guards covering the entire domain, any guarded pattern will be incomplete by definition.